# docker-compose can't use git submodule

Tags: git, docker, github, docker-compose, git-submodules

I try to build a docker container from git with docker-compose but when I try to do "docker-compose build", it says:

```
Building network_monitor
ERROR: error initializing submodules: git: 'submodule' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
: exit status 1
```

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
    [...(irrelevant services)...]

    network_monitor:
        build: git://github.com/Kruemmelspalter/network_monitor#main
        ports:
            - "10380:80"
        volumes:
            - "./network_monitor/conf:/root/conf"
    [...(irrelevant services)...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first test the same build, using an HTTPS URL, not a `git://` one, using a [build context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#context) (in Dockerfile v2)

```
build: 
  context: github.com/Kruemmelspalter/network_monitor#main
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Or simply:

```
build: github.com/Kruemmelspalter/network_monitor#main
```

Comment: When I tried without the `#main`, it tried to use master but I'll try without

Comment: It works without the `https://` and I need the `#main` because else it would try to use the `master` branch

Comment: @HelloGriffin Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly. Can you check if this looks OK?

Comment: yes this looks ok, one can also simplify it to `build: github.com/Kruemmelspalter/network_monitor#main`

Comment: @HelloGriffin OK, got it. I have edited the answer, again.